# Create a leaflet map based on postal codes

Tags: r, leaflet

I have the dataframe below:

```
mapd<-structure(list(City = c("Henderson", "Henderson", "Los Angeles", 
"Fort Lauderdale", "Fort Lauderdale", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", 
"Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles"), State = c("Kentucky", 
"Kentucky", "California", "Florida", "Florida", "California", 
"California", "California", "California", "California"), Zip = c(42420, 
42420, 90036, 33311, 33311, 90032, 90032, 90032, 90032, 90032
), Sales = c(261.96, 731.94, 14.62, 957.5775, 22.368, 48.86, 
7.28, 907.152, 18.504, 114.9)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I want to create a `leaflet` map that will display the `Sales` and City via markers. I guess that I need to use shapefiles data for us to do this and follow the logic like below but Im confused by the fact that I do not know where to find us shapefiles and also that I do not have latitude and longitude data.:

```
library(rgdal)
# Make sure the name of the shape file matches the name of the shape file 
# from the ZIP archive
shp <- readOGR("geo_export_4e602fd1-be14-4590-8a68-fdbca198af8f.shp")

# Add count data
library(dplyr)
shp@data <- shp@data %>% left_join(mapd, by = c("zip" = "Zip"))
Example plot using leaflet.

library(leaflet)
leaflet(shp) 
leaflet(data = shp) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.numeric(Sales), label = ~as.character(City))
```

Comment: I would start with `usmap` from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/usmap/index.html)

Comment: You can use the tigris package to download shapefiles from the US Census Bureau, including ZCTAs, which are standardized zip codes. This is currently too broad, since it's about how you would make a map *if* you had shapefiles. Without the shapefile you're reading already, we can't actually do anything with your code or see the output

Comment: which file should I download from here based on my data? https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html

Comment: I don't know, it depends on what you're trying to do, the year of your data, the resolution you want to use, etc. You should read the technical docs and make that decision based on your project

Comment: I just want to create a leaflet map based on the postal codes I have. And the marker will display the relative sales. I do not know if shapefiles are needed or any other method

Comment: Then you somehow have to add geographic coordinates to your postcodes. The roure @camille suggested seems the easiest one: grab the shapefile with ZIP codes, `left_join` your data and apply to leaflet.

Comment: Like I said, those are decisions you need to make based on your data and what you're trying to present. Until then, this is too broad for SO because we can't make those decisions for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `zipcodeR` (if you don't need to show the city extents with a polygon). You can get the latitude and longitude for each zipcode using `geocode_zip`, then join the `lat` and `long` data to your original dataframe, then use `leaflet`.

```
library(zipcodeR)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

mapd %>%
  left_join(.,
            geocode_zip(mapd$Zip) %>% mutate(zipcode = as.numeric(zipcode)),
            by = c("Zip" = "zipcode")) %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(
    ~ lng,
    ~ lat,
    popup = ~ as.character(Sales),
    label = ~ as.character(City)
  )
```

Output

[image]

Comment: thanks that is what I was looking for